# How do I hover over the menu button and the selections appear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

What's Wrong with this jquery if I want to:
Hover over `#menu` (the whole thing) and then all the other menu selections appear beneath that. These selections are `.menubox`, but I grouped them all separate from `.menuboxSuperior` as `#others`. The top box which is always showing (menu) is called `.menuboxSuperior.` Also when I hover over the whole thing (`#menu`) I want the opacity to increase from 0.4 to 0.9 in 200ms.
None of this is working for me.
What should I do?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menubox').hide();

$('#menu').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(200 0.9);
});

$('#menu').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(200 0.4);
});

$('#menu').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#others').show();
});

$('#menu').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#others').hide();
});

});
```

THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: what does your HTML look like?

Comment: Your `fadeTo` function has invalid parameters(`fadeTo(200, 0.4)`). See [this](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing a comma

```
$(this).fadeTo(200 0.9);
$(this).fadeTo(200 0.4);
```

should be

```
$(this).fadeTo(200, 0.9);
$(this).fadeTo(200, 0.4);
```

most modern browsers have developer tools with a console that will show simple errors like this - firefox shows `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` in this case, and shows exactly which line in your code you have wrong. If you want to develop, use developer tools

Comment: Thanks guys it's sorted now :)